# How to enable LDAP with php IIS 6 and windows server 2003

Tags: php, iis, iis-6, ldap

I have been reading this answer and trying to understand it:
[How can I enable LDAP in PHP - Windows Server 2008](https://serverfault.com/questions/72447/how-can-i-enable-ldap-in-php-windows-server-2008)

LDAP is not showing up with `phpinfo()`

I installed PHP the same way as this person with webpi. The voted answer said to download the .dll files from a new zip download. The problem is that I can't seem to find the files...

Can someone give me a online tutorial or advice on how to get LDAP enabled?